# Why are Nuclear weapons exceptionally feared?

Tags: armed-conflict, nuclear-weapons, weapons

It has been general cultural knowledge since the US developed and dropped nuclear weapons in Japan that nuclear weapons are different to others, and a war with two similarly armed nuclear arsenals would destroy much of the world and should be avoided at all costs.

My understanding is they are known to be exceptional for the following reasons:

1. They are exceptionally damaging, and do not decern for civilian life.
2. They can be fired from within defensive positions, from continents away from conflict
3. If one country fires, then (due to existing military alliances) all others will fire in response - destroying much of the world
4. Locations where nuclear weapons have been dropped are uninhabitable for years due to radiation

Below I suggest that, when comparing to conventional heavy weapons, these are not exceptional reasons.

They are exceptionally damaging, and do not decern for civilian life.

- There are many weapons that have no decern for civilian life (Eg Russia using chemical warfare in Syria in 2000s) See also the firebombing of japan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Tokyo), FOAB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Father_of_All_Bombs), Dresden (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Dresden_in_World_War_II)
- If you want to destroy a city, it may take longer and use more weapons than dropping a nuke, but geo-politically there's not much difference between drop 1 nuke or dropping 1000 conventional bombs if the city and its inhabitance are wiped out either way.

They can be fired from within defensive positions, from continents away from conflict

- This is describing the vehicle for the bomb. You can attach other heavy weapons and have the similar capabilities (albeit as mentioned above, its not as efficient per weapon)

If one country fires, then (due to existing military alliances) all others will fire in response - destroying much of the world

- Similar to the use of chemical/biological weapons, just because one adversary uses them, it doesnt mean others will - because there are still international ethical, economic and political pressures that hold them against their use. Eg. If Russia dropped one on Kyiv, USA would not respond with another (I imagine they would respond with conventional inter-continental weapons or general military might and defeat them)

Locations where nuclear weapons have been dropped are uninhabitable for years due to radiation

- Levelled cities by conventional weapons are also uninhabitable for years (less years) until they're rebuilt. While having to abandon land due to conflict is terrible, the cost to rebuild could be spent to build a new city somewhere else.

So my question is, **considering these points what else makes them exceptional?** Or alternatively, how are these points invalid?

They are definitely more efficient per bomb, but I cannot believe pure damage/bomb is the only reason they completely define international geopolitics.

Comment: At the current time, the only method that humanity has to destroy almost all (if not all) human life on earth involves nuclear weapons. Is another reason really necessary? I think it is strange that you compare the destruction created by a singular nuclear weapon to the destruction created by 1000 conventional weapons. Why not compare it to 1000 nuclear weapons? If there is anything left to compare after 1000 nuclear weapons, of course....

Comment: Well the radiation that can kill people from thousands of miles away is definitely a hazard.

Comment: Why are people so afraid of conventional weapons, either? After all, a million bullets can cause the same amount of destruction as a single bomb! And why are we so afraid of bullets? A few dozen stones are surely just as dangerous as a bullet!

Comment: Hyperbolic discounting causes a bias towards fearing a small immediate risk, vs. a larger longer term risk.  There is also belief that a single person or few people can conspire to "push a button" to kill a large population.  A conventional war requires a lot more people to all agree or conspire to go kill that population.  Besides, if you get hit by a bullet, perhaps you can do something about it. If you get hit by a conventional bomb, perhaps you can prepare by being in a basement. Get hit directly by a nuclear bomb, you can't do anything. We're hardwired to not just give up.

Comment: Just pointing out: Hiroshima and Nagasaki were not rendered uninhabitable...

Answer (score 7):

OK, this seems like it should be obvious to any and all people, but let's go.

#### Potential for easily achieving extremely high direct death counts

WW2 saw massive loss of life.  Going into it, several nations had intent to follow the doctrines of General [Douhet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giulio_Douhet)'s [Command of the Air](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3827644-the-command-of-the-air), which could be summarized as "drop 300 tons of bombs on an enemy's capital and they will surrender".  A corollary favorite was "the bomber will always get through".

Starting with the Blitz (and Warsaw and Rotterdam bombings before that), Germany put that to test, but soon the Allies did much worse.  Dresden followed killing 25000 in one night (numbers are disputed) - after considerable studies and trials, the Allied had optimized a mix of explosive and incendiary bombs that *could, sometimes,* start firestorms.

In Japan, with different construction materials, the results were even "better".  Tokyo was bombed and about 100.000 people, died in one night.

But all this came at considerable effort.  Hundreds of planes were involved and were by then facing not much resistance from Germany and Japan.

Now, jump forward to Hiroshima and Nagasaki.  75000 deaths, by one plane, using a very rudimentary, low yield A bomb, on each of those mid-sized cities.

Sure, it had taken years for the Manhattan project to get there, but by [1980 the US had 23k bombs and the USSR 30k.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_nuclear_weapons_stockpiles_and_nuclear_tests_by_country)  Of mostly vastly higher yield.  And instead of targeting medium cities (350k for Hiroshima in 1945), you could just aim at megacities (Moscow 12M, New York City 8M).

Do the math.

#### Potential for destroying a country's infrastructure

Let's play a thought experiment.  You have 30 nukes at your disposal which you will not "waste" on military targets.  Instead you can drop them anywhere you want on the continental US to maximize immediate and long term deaths.

Let's see 1 for each of New York, Los Angeles, San Francisco, Houston and more big cities.

But then let's bomb each big harbor and big industrial areas as well.  Refineries, car plants, rail yards.  Choose carefully.

With 30 bombs I daresay you could do a good job at killing many people *and* durably destroying the complex supply chains that keep food at your local supermarket because farmers have tractors and fertilizers to work with.

Right now the US has 5k bombs and Russia 6k.  That 30 to play with is a joke compared to actual reality, even if many of those aren't intercontinental and many are mothballed.

#### [Nuclear winter theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter)

This is, roughly speaking the idea that sufficient nuclear strikes would block sunlight and cause mass agricultural failure.  So, now it's not the just the US and Russia's problems it is everyone's.

Would everyone get killed?  90%?  25%?  Is this theory even [really valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_winter#Criticism_and_debate)? `*`  You really want to find out?

#### Radiation

Past their immediate effect, nuclear bombs, as everyone knows, also release radiation for long periods of time.  Nagasaki and Hiroshima were both air bursts which comparatively less radiation, so that the long term outcome may look less bad than it could have been otherwise but I wouldn't want to see the results of generalized bombings.  Chernobyl, though not strictly comparable, will be uninhabitable for a long time.  Radiation, even when it doesn't kill right away, is known for increasing cancer rates. Strontium-90, one of the primary vectors of concerns for it has a [half-life of 28 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strontium-90).

#### Any one nuclear bomb is not a huge problem, but...

The world didn't end with Hiroshima or Nagasaki.  In fact, one can argue that Mutually Assured Destruction has kept NATO and the Warsaw pact from engaging in WW3 several times over.

**But this is all predicated on those bombs really, really, being taboo.  And that no one should ever use even ONE of them, ever again.**

Break that taboo, get a chain of escalation going and nuclear countries could start launching their massive missile stockpiles at each other.  Arrival time is about 25 minutes and there is no way to stop them.

Your question, implying that they are somewhat not qualitatively different from other weapons, strikes me as fundamentally misunderstanding their nature and hopelessly naive, for all the research you quote.

“Quantity has a quality all its own” (Stalin?) comes to mind here.  If all we had were 10-100 nukes on each side then it would be a very different weapon from the others, yes.  A banned weapon, like maybe combat gases.  More banned!  Something good people don't use!  *But it wouldn't be sitting there as a existential risk.*  The sheer numbers are what are driving this aversion, by necessity.

Nothing, nothing, comes close to it, except for a super-efficient self-propagating plague bio-weapon (anthrax for one is more something you catch by direct exposure than something you pass on to others).

And I say that as someone who mostly thinks that MAD *has* fulfilled its purpose, to break the cycle of big power global wars.

`*` growing about that time I remember we went extremely quickly from never having heard of Nuclear Winter to it becoming "common sense".  It was a brilliant way to focalize everyone on the risks, and we have had [volcanic eruption research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toba_catastrophe_theory) backing the general idea as plausible science.  But it still has become pretty much gospel with only minimal public examination of its foundations.  Which is not the same thing as saying I believe it is wrong.

Comment: Generally a good summary, but I think you are underestimating the importance of fallout compared to the other factors.

Comment: Possibly, even likely.  But I really dont have any hard data to work with there.  We had a bunch of air bursts in the 50s and 60s and the world is still around.  People do live in Hiroshima and Nagasaki.  I don't want to project doom where we are just speculating, even if I am pretty sure it wouldn't be fun.

Comment: Thanks yeah this is a solid answer. Although the focus on both these answers is about relative damage, and logistical ease of use. When talking about their effect on global politics, the size and quantity become irrelevant above a certain point. 

Interesting point on MAD only working if the taboo is strong, that goes some way to see how we are here culturally. I don’t actually believe it would be tit for tat if someone dropped a nuke on the US. They would go to war, but they wouldn’t choose to continue escalating a nuclear conflict

Comment: Nuclear fallout is by far the most dangerous part of the nuke. Like @o.m. said underestimated. Still a clear and good answer though.

Comment: @BruhMoments point me to some factual information that I can use and I might incorporate it.  For now, I confess that this is not something I have any great amount of insight on.

Answer (score 2):

A large WWII bomb was equivalent to 2000 lbs of TNT. Little Boy (dropped on Hiroshima) was by itself equivalent to 15 kilotons (15,000) lbs of TNT. In the modern nuclear arsenal, it's common to find weapons with 100 kiloton yields, and many that stretch up over several million tons. The entire yield of the bombing of Dresden was approximately 3,900 tons (3.9 kilotons) over three days by almost 800 delivery vectors, and it nearly leveled the city. Little Boy was roughly four times more powerful than that entire Dresden raid; a modern 'big nuke' could be almost 4000 times more powerful, and both require only a single delivery vector.

Power isn't the only concern here; speed and effort come into play. Conventional weapons are somewhat self-limiting, because their comparatively slow delivery speed and the necessity of many multiple strikes means that it's possible to mount a defense and move civilian populations to shelters. An ICBM can strike within minutes and level an entire city; there is no sure line of defense, and no time to shelter populations from the blast. Kill-rate for nukes is exceedingly high: imagine a school shooter with a weapon that can kill 300 people a second (as opposed to the current 2-3 kills per second typical of the weaponry used in school shootings) and you might understand the fear.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I understand how powerful they are and easy to fire. Altho ICBMs can carry other bombs, so a Dresden equivalent could happen with a couple hundred MOABs attached to them in a matter of mins and impossible to prepare for